# @Mock, NullPointerException

Tags: spring, mockito

The first case works, while the second returns a NullPointerException for userDao. Did I totally misunderstand how this works?

This works

```
UserDao userDao;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    userDao = Mockito.mock(UserDao.class);
    when(userDao.userExists("TestUser")).thenReturn(true);
}
```

NullPointerException for userDao

```
@Mock
private UserDao userDao;

@InjectMocks
private UserService userService;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    when(userDao.userExists("TestUser")).thenReturn(true); // NPE
}
```

Comment: Try adding in the `@Before` method this: `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`. See [here](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html) details about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` to the `@Before` method to create the `@Mock` annotated fields. See [here](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html) details about this:

> MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) method has to called to initialize annotated mocks.
>     In above example, initMocks() is called in @Before (JUnit4) method of test's base class. For JUnit3 initMocks() can go to setup() method of a base class. You can also put initMocks() in your JUnit runner (@RunWith) or use built-in runners: MockitoJUnit44Runner, MockitoJUnitRunner